# firebird, função nativa para formatar data

Tags: firebird

Existe uma função nativa do firebird que formate a data(date)?

Assim como no Mysql temos a função DATE_FORMAT() teria algo similar no firebird?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebird não possui uma função pronta para formatar data. Acredito que você pode criar uma procedure que retorna uma data formatada.Segue um SELECT para retornar a data no formato dd/MM/yyyy.

```
SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM Campo) || '/' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM
Campo) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Campo) AS VARCHAR) AS DIA_MES_ANO FROM Tabela;
```

Procedure que passa um valor inteiro que retorna a data de acordo com um país, neste caso Brasil igual a 1 e EUA igual a 2 para a variável res declarada como retorno.

```
create procedure formatdate(locale int) returns (res date)
begin

    // Formato brasileiro
    IF (locale = 1) THEN BEGIN
       SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM Campo) || '/' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM
        Campo) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Campo) AS VARCHAR) AS DIA_MES_ANO FROM Tabela INTO res;
    END;

    // Formato americano
    IF (locale = 2) THEN BEGIN
       SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Campo) || '/' || EXTRACT(DAY FROM
        Campo) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Campo) AS VARCHAR) AS DIA_MES_ANO FROM Tabela INTO res;
    END;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizo uma proc para isso.

```
 create or alter procedure SP_FORMATA_DATA (
        DATA DATA)
    returns (
        RESULTADO varchar(10))
    as
    BEGIN
      -- Sem data?
      IF(DATA IS NULL)THEN
        -- Sem resultado tambem.
        RESULTADO = NULL;
      ELSE
        -- Converte a data p/ texto no formato brasileiro.
        RESULTADO = (LPAD(EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATA), 2, '0') || '/' ||
                     LPAD(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATA), 2, '0') || '/' ||
                     LPAD(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATA), 4, '0'));
      -- Retorna o resultado.
      SUSPEND;
    END
```

E para chamar a proc:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_FORMATA_DATA('2014.04.14')
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui eu uso Visual Studio 2015 e utilizo assim nas rotinas de consulta por datas

where ( SUBSTRING( DST001.DATA_FAT FROM 7 FOR 4 )||SUBSTRING( DST001.DATA_FAT FROM 4 FOR 2 )||SUBSTRING( DST001.DATA_FAT FROM 1 FOR 2 )) BETWEEN '" & ANOMESDIA_INI & "' And '" & ANOMESDIA_FIM & "'" &

tenta assim
 No meu BD armazeno as datas como varchar(10) - DD/MM/YYYY
Eu pego as datas de um datetimepicker e monto as strings anomesdia.
ANOMESDIA_INI as string = "20170919"
ANOMESDIA_FIM as string = "20170922"

Answer (score 0):

Não existe, mas comigo funcionou desta forma no Firebird no formato yyyy-mm-dd :

```sql
SELECT
(extract(year from campo_data)||'-'||extract(month from campo_data)||'-'||extract(day from campo_data)||' '||campo_hora) AS DATA_HORA
from tabela
```

Concatenei um campo hora no final caso precise para ficar yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).